# incorrect pointer value passed to a C function

Tags: c, pointers, inline, type-punning

I have a bug in which an incorrect value gets passed as an argument to a function in a C program. The way it works is, I declare a static pointer to a typedef-ed data structure as a global variable. There is an initialization function where this variable is initialized. This function allocates memory, initializes data fields and returns the pointer. Something like this:

```
static my_type *my_ptr;
...
void init(void){
   my_ptr = init_my_type();
}
```

The function `init_my_type` is pretty straight forward:

```
void *init_my_type(void){
   my_type *x = malloc(sizeof(my_type);
   x->arg1 = 0;
   ... // more field initializations
   return x;
}
```

Later on I use `my_ptr` as an argument to another function:

```
void do_stuff(void){
   func(my_ptr);
}
```

The problem I have is that I seg fault in the guts of `func` when some of the data in the data structure that `my_ptr` points to is accessed.

When I run the debugger I get a nice looking hex value when I break on the  `init_my_type`:

```
(gdb) finish
Value returned is $26 (void *) 0x79b6c0
```

Later, inside the `do_stuff` function, `my_ptr` has the same hex value:

```
(gdb) print my_ptr
$26 = (my_type *) 0x79b6c0
```

but, when I break on `func` the argument it gets has a totally different value.

```
Breakpoint 2, func(arg=0x1388)
```

I am type-punning pointers all over the place, but I don't see that that should change the address in memory that they point to, right? Also, the function `func` is declared `inline` but why should that affect this? This all seems correct to me -- it is entirely possible that I'm doing something stupid that I don't see.

Here is a complete program of the simplified code. In reality, all these functions don't get called by main, but by dynamically loaded helper functions. Still, I don't see how the address pointed to by `my_ptr` should change when passed to `func`.

```
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "stdio.h"

typedef struct _type{
  int *i1;
  float *f1;
}my_type;

static my_type *my_ptr;

void *init_my_type(void){

  my_type *x = malloc(sizeof(my_type));
  x->f1 = malloc(sizeof(float));
  x->i1 = malloc(sizeof(int));
  x->f1[0] = 123.456;
  x->i1[0] = 789;

  return x;

}

void init(void){

  my_ptr = init_my_type();

}

inline void func(void *arg){

  my_type *x = (my_type *)arg;
  printf("%d %f\n", *x->i1, *x->f1);

}

void do_stuff(void){

  func(my_ptr);

}


int main(void){

  init();
  do_stuff();


}
```

Comment: Please post a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem you're experiencing.  It's impossible to tell what's going on based on what little code is here so far.

Comment: Can you please tell me what isn't clear? I included all the parts in as concise a way imaginable. I then step through my debugging process exactly as it appears. To me this is completely clear, but I wrote the code and think about it all day. Please give me more information.

Comment: Could you please post the code of your `init_my_type()` function? Segfaults are often caused by dereferencing uninitialized pointers

Comment: @dmedine, you don't give `func` where the error appears. How do you think we should guess this. And really MCVE is important for us, such that we can quickly check what is going on, and it is important for you since it helps clarify your code.

Comment: added code for initialization function.

Comment: Returning a pointer when return type is void? Or is that just what you put now for keeping it concise?

Comment: Expanding on bpgeck's comment, a seg fault can occur in a part of the code completely unrelated to where the bug actually is.  That's why a compilable piece of code exhibiting the problem is necessary.

Comment: @Jens The problem is that the pointer value passed to func is incorrect. The data pointed to by `my_ptr` is, I believe, all there and allocated properly. Should not the value passed to `func` be the address stored in `my_ptr`? This is my question.

Comment: Also, I can add compilable code, but this is a small piece of a very, very, very large project. It can get unconcise very fast. I have tried to strip it down to the essentials.I'm not sure how to add a complete example of this without recreating the entire world.

Comment: @bpgeck The return type of `init_my_ptr` isn't void, it is a pointer to void. Type punning. In the context, these init functions are a type unto themselves (different instances get called by an engine that looks for these types), hence the generic return value. Sorry this is so unclear.

Comment: In that case, I'd recommend running your code under valgrind.  If you're accessing memory you shouldn't be, it will tell you.

Comment: @dbush Thanks. I will give it a whirl. Still, I am deeply troubled by the fact that `func` isn't getting the value of `my_ptr`. This doesn't make any sense to me. I want to understand this.

Comment: @dmedine, if `func()` is receiving the wrong argument value then it is the code of the relevant caller that we need to see.  This is, again, why we need an MCVE.  Moreover, it is sometimes the case that going through the process of producing an MCVE from your program leads you to discover the error for yourself.

Comment: I put the simplified code into the question. As expected it works just fine. In the real code, this is all nestled several layers and dynamic libraries deep. Still, it very much of this structure. Of course, it 's likely that I am missing something stupid. I guess I was just fishing for insight from someone that has had a similar problem.

Comment: I would run the code in `gdb`,  break at allocation of the pointer, note the address of the pointer of interest, set a memory `watch` on all memory write to the said pointer and see what is mucking your pointer.

Comment: FWIW, I just built your sample code with Visual Studio 10 and it runs without error.  I needed to change inline to __inline and add an 'f' suffix to the x->f1[0] = 123.456f; statement, but otherwise it compiled and ran exactly as you provided it.

Comment: Yeah... works for me too in Linux (without the MSVC adjustments).

Comment: I'd guess that you are compiling on 64-bit platform and `init_my_type` is not declared at the point of the call (inside `init`). The compiler assumes it returns `int` and trims the 64-bit pointer value to 32-bit `int` value. This trimmed value is what is then passed to `func`. If that's the case, then you must have ignored a bunch of warnings from the compiler.

Comment: Is it possible that the actual code is malloc(sizeof(my_ptr)) instead of malloc(sizeof(my_type)) ?  That could cause 'interesting' problems and is an easy mistake to make.

Comment: @AnT This is very interesting! This may well be the situation. I will have to spend some time investigating this, but I will definitely check this out. If this is the case, I'm not quite sure how to avoid it. Perhaps if I compile my library (in which `init_my_type`) is declared statically instead of as a dynamic one. However, I am following this procedure all over the place, and there is just the one place where this mangling occurs. I need to follow  the recommendations of vincentlesst dbush.

Comment: @Steve Valliere: If only it were that simple! The malloc call is definitely correct. BTW, thanks to everyone for all the help! I have been stuck and baffled by this for 24 hours. There is now a lot for me to go on here. Cheers to all of the stackoverflowers out there!

Comment: Was the code you're running in the debugger compiled without optimizations?  If not, try it... even if it still doesn't work you'll get more reliable information in the debugger.

Comment: @AnT After some investigation, I suspect that this is not the case (see my comment to Daniel Jour below) I am inclined to conclude that this was all based on a red herring and that there is some conventional misallocation of memory that is causing the snag. A most stimulating conversation, though, thanks again to all those that took the time to think about this with me!

Answer (score 0):

The following is not the cause of the issue (and can't, since static globals are initialised to zero by default). Though the basic idea is still relevant: whether the passed pointer is really the same that got initialised.

---

A wild guess:

```
static my_type *my_ptr;
```

Could it be that this line is part of some header file? Because then you have a global `my_ptr` in every source file that includes this header.

Since you wrote that this is a very large project, I assume that you separated the code and put it into multiple source files. Assuming the init function is in a different source file than the using function, then this would mean they're accessing different pointers. While the one `init` deals with gets initialised, the one `func` is using is uninitialised.

To check this you should print the address of the global pointer variable (`&my_ptr`) in both functions.

Comment: Hmmm. `my_ptr` is declared in the same file that calls `func`. `init_my_func` is in a different file, but `init` is not. According to my (limited) understanding, since `my_ptr` is declared in the same file as `init`, then the value returned by `init_my_func` (called by `init`) is OK.

Comment: OK, then I guessed wrong. But still, can you print (from the actual code, not the debugger) the address of the pointer both at init and use?

Comment: If the different value that func() saw was zero, the static thing would make sense because C defines static variables to be automatically initialized to zero before they are referenced.  However, that was not the case.

Comment: Indeed, still @dmedine I think it would be helpful to know that you're using the same global in both places, in the context of "called [...] by dynamically loaded helper functions."

Comment: @Daniel Jour Yes, you are absolutely correct. I will get that information up as soon as I have time to grab it.

Comment: @Daniel Jour I have printed the pointers in both contexts and they appear to be correct both times. Something funny in the debugger -- or (more likely) I'm not using correctly has sent me on a snark hunt. The bug is apparently  elsewhere and probably not as mysterious as I feared. Although, it is still difficult to track down.