# wrong address value being passed to function in C

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management

This is similar to [incorrect pointer value passed to a C function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31883366/incorrect-pointer-value-passed-to-a-c-function) but there doesn't appear to be an answer.

I have a struct, called `bigint`, which has fields `char sign`, `size_t len` and `uint32_t *val`. `bigint`s are initialized by a `bigint_init()` function which allocates some memory for the `uint32_t` array, sets default values, etc.

I have a function, `void bigint_subtract(bigint a, bigint b, bigint *diff)` which stores `a-b` in `diff`. I have tested this function previously, as follows:

```
bigint test = bigint_inithex("4567890987654345678987654adbfcaedcfaaebfc625213");
bigint test2 = bigint_inithex("acbefabedfc13271723976aebdfcabefc12837618237");
bigint diff = bigint_init();
bigint_subtract(test,test2,&diff);
printf("0x%s - 0x%s == 0x%s\n\n",bigint_tohex(test), bigint_tohex(test2),bigint_tohex(diff));
```

among numerous other tests for edge cases, varying lengths, etc. All the tests check out.

Now, I am in another function, `void bigint_egcd(bigint a, bigint b, bigint c, bigint *x, bigint *y);` It's just the extended euclidean algorithm. In the main loop of the extended Euclidean algorithm, I have the following code:

```
bigint rold, rnew, q, r, ...;
rold = bigint_init();
bigint_cpy(&rold, a);
rnew = bigint_init();
bigint_cpy(&rnew, b);
...[more initializations, etc.]

while(!bigint_isval(rnew, 0)){
    bigint_divide(rold,rnew,&q,&r);

    bigint_cpy(&tmp1, rnew); 
    bigint_multiply(q,rnew,&tmp2); 
    bigint_subtract(rold,tmp2,&rnew); 
    bigint_cpy(&rold, tmp1);
    ....
}
```

Things were going wrong, so I did some debugging, couldn't figure anything out, so I started adding printfs. Here's how it looks now:

```
while(!bigint_isval(rnew, 0)){
    bigint_divide(rold,rnew,&q,&r);

    printf("\t%s = %s * %s + %s\n", bigint_tohex(rold), bigint_tohex(rnew), bigint_tohex(q), bigint_tohex(r));fflush(stdout);
    bigint_cpy(&tmp1, rnew); 
    printf("\tupdated r = %s - %s * %s = ", bigint_tohex(rold), bigint_tohex(q), bigint_tohex(rnew));fflush(stdout);
    bigint_multiply(q,rnew,&tmp2); 
    printf("%s - %s = (%p) ", bigint_tohex(rold), bigint_tohex(tmp2), &rnew);fflush(stdout);
    bigint_subtract(rold,tmp2,&rnew); 
    printf("%s at address %p\n", bigint_tohex(rnew),&rnew);fflush(stdout);
    bigint_cpy(&rold, tmp1);
```

At the beginning of `bigint_subtract`, I added the following printf:

```
void bigint_subtract(bigint a, bigint b, bigint *diff){
    printf("BIGINT_SUBTRACT diff address is %p\n", diff);fflush(stdout);
    ....
```

And so I discovered that the address being received by `bigint_subtract` is not the same as the address I am passing to it in `bigint_egcd`. Meanwhile, the subtraction is actually correct, it's just storing it some random address, and not updated the value stored at `rnew`.

Meanwhile, the exact same code later in the loop, with `t` and `s` in place of their `r` counterparts, does not exhibit this behavior -- all the addresses are passed correctly. `rnew` and `rold` are properly initialized at the top of `bigint_egcd`, in the exactly same way as the `t` and `s` counterparts are.

In short, I have a variable `bar1`.  I pass `&bar1` to `foo(type *var)`, but somehow it becomes something else once inside of `foo`. What gives? What kinds of mistakes could cause this to happen?

EDIT

Here's `bigint_tohex`:

```
static const char *BII_HEX="0123456789abcdef";

char *bigint_tohex(bigint a){
    char *hex = calloc((a.len<<3) + 1,sizeof(char));
    uint8_t j;
    for(size_t i=0; i<a.len; i++){
        for(j=0; j<8; j++){
            hex[ (i<<3) + j ] = BII_HEX[(a.val[i] >> ((7-j)<<2)) & 0xF];
        }
    }
    hex[a.len<<3] = 0;

    //any leading 0s should be removed:
    int i=0;
    while(hex[i]=='0' && hex[i+1]!=0) ++i;

    memmove(hex,hex+i,strlen(hex)+1-i);

    if(a.sign == BII_NEG){
        hex = realloc(hex, (strlen(hex)+1)*sizeof(char));
        memmove(hex+1,hex,strlen(hex)+1);
        hex[0]='-';
    }
    return hex;
}
```

Comment: what is the type of `rnew`?

Comment: `bigint`. Editing to make it clear.

Comment: So you're saying that when you have these statements: `printf("%s - %s = (%p) ", bigint_tohex(rold), bigint_tohex(tmp2), &rnew);fflush(stdout); bigint_subtract(rold,tmp2,&rnew);` the pointer displayed for `&rnew` is not the same as when `diff` is printed in the `bigint_subtract()` call?  You should post a *small*, compilable example that shows the problem.

Comment: I also wonder about what is being returned from `bigint_tohex()`? You likely either have a memory leak, undefined behavior, or you're returning the address of a static buffer - which won't work well when used more than once in a single `printf()` call (or you're really using C++, not C).  In an case, you almost certainly have a bug there.

Comment: @MichaelBurr OK, I will work on a minimal example in the morning (midnight here).

Comment: It looks like you would need to be getting several warnings during compilation.. Right ?

Comment: It seems a compiler optimization bug. Which compiler are you using? Try first of all to compile with no optimization, then as workaround try declaring `volatile` the affected variable: `volatile bigint rnew;` and check again if it works with optimizations on this time. If it works post a bug report on compiler forum.

Comment: @marcolz in fact, no, compiling with clang -Wall

Comment: @Frankie_C I'm using clang. Compiling with `clang -O0` did not fix the issue, nor did setting `rnew` to be volatile. If I understand correctly, what `volatile` does is alert the compiler that the value being stored at `&rnew` might change without anything seeming to directly access `rnew`, but I don't see why, if that was happening, the wrong address would be getting passed to `bigint_subtract`.

Comment: If removing optimization the problem persist the compiler is ok. The use of `volatile`, in case of a broken optimizer, sometimes solves the problem because instruct the compiler to reload values bypassing the use of corrupted registers.

Comment: I'm still thinking of a compiler bug. You're right I told you to make volatile the value of `rnew`, but we need address to be reloaded. Try defining a new pointer, `volatile`, that holds the address of `rnew`: `volatile bigint *bip = &rnew;`, then pass the pointer to the function `bigint_subtract`. Then if still no light, there are only 2 ways: inspect the generated assembler, check for a **side-effect** of some instruction in your code.

Comment: @Frankie_C Tried this, no cigar. I should note that clang issued a warning:
`CBigInt_numtheory.c:47:29: warning: passing 'volatile bigint *' (aka 'volatile struct bigint *') to parameter of type 'bigint *'
      (aka 'struct bigint *') discards qualifiers [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
                bigint_subtract(rold,tmp2,rnewp); `

EDIT nevermind I'm being dumb, hold on a minute...

Comment: @MichaelBurr I made a self-contained c file containing only the necessary code for this operation, and of course the problem disappeared. Now investigating the differences. I deleted some printfs, so I suspect you're onto something about the static buffer, which I don't know what that is but I'm about to go learn!

Comment: @MichaelBurr So you're right, adding the printfs back in causes the problem to re-emerge. If I understand correctly, a static buffer is one initialized as follows: `char staticBuf[10];`, right? I am very careful never to do this anywhere, using calloc always. If you don't mind, could you just elaborate a bit on what I should look for, or point me to a reference?

Comment: Post the code for `bigint_tohex()`

Comment: @MichaelBurr posted.

Comment: @MichaelBurr I was wrong, removing printfs did NOT fix the issue, I looked at the wrong output.

Comment: Possible error sources could also be overwriting part of the stack, e.g in one of the `bigint_cpy` functions. Can you show the other functions, or alternatively try to make 100% sure they're working as they should? (Some questions just haunt you :D )

Comment: @gmoss: the `bigint_tohex()` fucntion returns a dynamically allocated string so it isn't causing the kind of problem that I thought might be possible (such as returning a pointer to a local variable).  However, that does mean you have a memory leak using it directly from a `printf()` call.  That's fine for debugging/troubleshooting but is something that you have to keep in mind for normal use.  Also, I think you might have a bug in the bit of code prepending a minus sign (I think the realloc'ed buffer might be too small by one).